# Counting the number of elements in a dataframe

Tags: r, dataset

I have a dataframe like this :

```
mydata
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12] [,13]
 [1,] "-"  "-"  "-"  "-"  "+"  "+"  "-"  "-"  "+"  "-"   "0"   "-"   "0"  
 [2,] "-"  "+"  "-"  "+"  "-"  "-"  "-"  "-"  "+"  "+"   "-"   "+"   NA   
 [3,] "+"
```

For each row, how to count the number of elements according "-" or "+" or "0" ?

For example, for the first row, we have 8 element for "-" and for the last row we have : 1  for "+" and 0 for "-" and 0 for "0"

I used `table(mydata)` but I dont get the expected result. Indeed, for the last row its only gave me 1 for "+" (I also want 0 for "-" and 0 for "0")

Comment: Can you please provide the code to build that `data.frame`? I am not sure if the empty spaces are "" or something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can still use `table` using a trick.

Some sample data:

```
set.seed(2)
m <- matrix(sample(c('-','+','0'),size=39,replace=TRUE,prob=c(0.45,0.45,0.1)), nrow=3)
m
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12] [,13]
# [1,] "+"  "+"  "+"  "-"  "-"  "-"  "+"  "+"  "+"  "+"   "+"   "-"   "-"  
# [2,] "-"  "0"  "-"  "-"  "+"  "0"  "+"  "-"  "-"  "0"   "+"   "-"   "+"  
# [3,] "-"  "0"  "-"  "+"  "+"  "+"  "-"  "+"  "+"  "+"   "-"   "-"   "-"
```

The trick is to *add all values*, then subtract 1 from the table:

```
apply(m, 1, function(a) table(c('-','+','0',a))-1L)
#   [,1] [,2] [,3]
# -    5    6    6
# +    8    4    6
# 0    0    3    1
```

Since it is transposed, some prefer it to remain row-wise relevant:

```
t(apply(m, 1, function(a) table(c('-','+','0',a))-1))
#      - + 0
# [1,] 5 8 0
# [2,] 6 4 3
# [3,] 6 6 1
```

NB: `apply` will return a `matrix` if and only if all rows return the same sized object. In this case, since we *know* all possible input values, then with our `table` trick assures us that we will always have `integer` vectors of length 3. If there is something else, then it will be returned as a ragged `list`.

In a special case, if you also want to know the number of `NA`s, you also need to tell `table` to include them in the totals:

```
t(apply(m, 1, function(a) table(c('-','+','0',a,NA),useNA='always')-1L))
#      - + 0 <NA>
# [1,] 5 8 0    0
# [2,] 6 4 3    0
# [3,] 6 6 1    0
m[1,2] <- NA
t(apply(m, 1, function(a) table(c('-','+','0',a,NA),useNA='always')-1L))
#      - + 0 <NA>
# [1,] 5 7 0    1
# [2,] 6 4 3    0
# [3,] 6 6 1    0
```

(The order of adding the "known values" is not important, as you can see here.)

Answer (score 0):

I found solution. I just have to do (for example the first row) :

```
count(mydata[1,][mydata[1,]=="+"])
```

which give `3`.

Its the same thing for "-" or "0", just remplace in the code "+" by "-" or "0" to get the result

Comment: If you want to do one value at a time, you could at least do, e.g.,  `rowSums(yourdata == "+")` to get all the rows at once. But use r2evans's answer for a all-values-at-once approach.